# HTML/CSS image scaling leaves blank space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image gallery scale properly to the rest of my website but whenever it scales down, it leaves a blank space at where the gallery image would have been.

```
<div style="position: relative;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: black;
            height:100%;">

    <div class="slider" id="main-slider">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <img style="height:auto;width:100%;" src="style/slides/img1" alt="First" class="slide"/>
            <img style="height:auto;width:100%;" src="style/slides/img2" alt="Second" class="slide"/>
            <img style="height:auto;width:100%;" src="style/slides/img3" alt="Third" class="slide"/>
            <img style="height:auto;width:100%;" src="style/slides/img4" alt="Fourth" class="slide"/>
            <img style="height:auto;width:100%;" src="style/slides/img5" alt="Last" class="slide"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    .slider {
    height: auto;width:100%;
    margin: 2em auto;
    position:absolute;  
}

.slider-wrapper {
    height: auto;width:100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;width:100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 6s linear;
}

.slider-wrapper > .slide:first-child {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

All images are `1920x1080`

Comment: I copied your code into a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vypvaj5e/ and can't really see your issue. If this is hosted anywhere, can you send the link? Or some screenshots?

Comment: @Suavocado [The black space is what I am talking about](https://gyazo.com/a37e9c1f57522f4b7a131bc3f3a0b4fa)

Comment: @Suavocado [Different window size](https://gyazo.com/33fb249b4822be998970ee3bdda75ae3)

Comment: There is an problem with position value update parent element and slider next element. Or try to set slider next element position:relative to slider.